# How does the dtype parameter of numpy.empty function work?

Tags: python, numpy, memory

When I do not include the dtype parameter, then I think I roughly understand the mechanism. Say I write:

**Code block 1**

```
import numpy as np

test=np.empty((1,2))

print(test)
```

Output:

```
[[-2.00000000e+000  6.80176343e-310]]
```

I understand what is happening here. The operating system allocates a (contiguous) block of memory to the array `test`. The test just takes the arbitrary values already present in the cells of the memory block. Great!

Now, let's change the code a bit:

**Code block 2**

```
import numpy as np

test=np.empty((1,2), dtype=int)

print(test)
```

Output

`[[4611686018427387904     137669224398847]]`

My question is, how did the operating system find a memory block that specifically only had integers? This seems miraculous. My guess is that in reality the operating system found a memory with float64 numbers, but just truncated everything after the decimal to make it an integer. Is my guess correct? I have another question: even if I run the code blocks 1 and 2 multiple times, the output doesn't change. That's so strange. I expected the outputs to change with each iteration. I thought that the operating system would assign the array "test" to different memory blocks with each iteration. It seems as though the operating system is assigning the array "test" to the same memory block over and over again. Weird. Only when I change the shape is the output changed. Could you please explain the cause behind the output not changing?

Comment: It defaults to float (per https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html), so whatever happens to be there is interpreted as if it was float data. If you set it to int, whatever's there is interpreted as if it was int data. But when you use an empty array you shouldn't be doing _anything_ with its content, except overwriting it.

Comment: Memory blocks don't have a type, float or inr.  It's the code, in this case numpy, that interprets the raw bytes as numbers.  Don't attribute any meaning to the values you see, float or int.  Don't even think of them as 'random'

Comment: Numpy does not directly request memory space to the OS. It request space to CPython which may request space to the libc, and the libc may request space to the OS. CPython and the libc can keep a buffer cache of allocated data. In fact, the libc does. It is called `sbrk`. In practice the libc request a big block and split it in parts. Parts can be recycled.  `np.empty` returns an array which the data buffer point on such a part. As pointed out by hpaulj, data is interpreted regarding the target data-type provided.

Comment: When you get a part of the pre-allocated memory from the libc, the bytes are not reset to zero (it would be slow), but the OS can do that when the libc request some additional space (for security reasons, despite the performance impact). The last allocated data buffer tends to be recycled first because they are in cache (so accessing it will be faster than in-RAM pre-allocated data). This is why `v = np.ones(5); del v; v = np.empty(5); print(v)`, typically prints `[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]` on many machines (though you should not assume that since this is implementation-dependent)

Comment: The way all of this works it a bit more complex in practice. There is a lot more to say but it is too much for a StackOverflow post. If you want to know more, then I advise you to read books about system programming (about OS, virtual memory, allocators, the libc, CPU architectures, etc.). There are many books on the internet, even good free ones nowadays. Alternatively Wikipedia may help a bit too.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how did the operating system find a memory block that specifically only had integers?

It doesn't necessarily have to be memory that was previously used for integers.

It found a block of memory, and whatever was there before, it re-interpreted them as integers.

Here's an example of re-interpreting memory. I take the numbers 0 through 9, as floating point numbers. Then, I re-interpret them as integers using [ndarray.view()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10, dtype='float64')
print(a)
b = a.view('int64')
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
[                  0 4607182418800017408 4611686018427387904
 4613937818241073152 4616189618054758400 4617315517961601024
 4618441417868443648 4619567317775286272 4620693217682128896
 4621256167635550208]
```

When you take the bits which make up 1 in floating point, and re-interpret them as an integer, you get a completely different number.

> I have another question: even if I run the code blocks 1 and 2 multiple times, the output doesn't change.

The memory allocator could be giving you back the same block of memory you just freed. It's the perfect size, after all, and you're not using it anymore.

Here's an example that demonstrates this. I allocate an empty array. I determine what address it's at. I add this to a set, to find out how many unique addresses the array gets stored at. Then I loop. I only keep a reference to the most recent array, `a`.

```
import numpy as np
pointers = set()
for i in range(100):
    a = np.empty(10)
    pointer, read_only_flag = a.__array_interface__['data']
    pointers.add(pointer)
    print(pointer)
print(f"{len(pointers)=}")
```

You might expect that this leads to a hundred different addresses. But the memory allocator is more clever than that: it can tell that all but one of the arrays I allocated are no longer referenced, and it can re-use that memory. It only shows two unique pointers.

Lots of programs that use NumPy allocate and free many NumPy arrays over time. (As an example, if `a` and `b` are arrays, then `a = a + b` allocates and frees one array.) It would be wasteful if the memory allocator couldn't re-use memory that has been freed.

The other possible explanation is that this same pattern appears multiple times in memory, from something else Python was doing. There's not enough information to say which one is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is not how memory works.

Well, in interpreted languages (such as python), each data (each value) is accompanied by a descriptor, giving its type. So an int or a float is already a quite complex structure, that you don't expect to find randomly.

But numpy is more C than python. It is python binding to a mainly C library.

So, what `np.empty` does, is just the C equivalent of `malloc`. It finds a memory place without bothering about what it is it. And allocate it. And note somewhere that this memory content is to be interpreted as a bunch of data of given dtype.

For example, `np.empty((1,2))` finds 1×2×8 bytes (needed to store 1 row of 2 number of type float64) = 16 bytes of memory. So does a `malloc(16)`. And that memory is, for now on, to be interpreted as `float64`.

Almost any random bytes are a float (it would be a waste of bits if not all combination of bits were meaning something. That would mean that we don't represent as many possible value as we could with bytes).

So, whatever are those 16 bytes, you can interpret then as 2 floats (and if you couldn't, then, they are NaN. So it is still something)

In your example, those 16 bytes that were already in the memory when numpy decided to use them for your `test` array, happened to be

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 22, 148, 56, 157, 53, 125, 0, 0]
```

So interpreted as float64, the first 8 bytes are (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,192). We must read that backward. That is (192,0,0,0,0,0,0,0). That is in binary

```
11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

If you choose to interpret those 64 bits as representing a float, then first bit is 1, so it is a negative number.
Then the next 11 bits are 1, followed by ten 0. So, exponent is 10000000000, or, in decimal 1024. Since exponent, in float64 are relative to 1023 (1023 is exponent 0, 1024, exponent 1, 1025 exponent 2, 1022 exponent -1, 1021 exponent -2, ...), the exponent here is 1.

Then the remaining 52 bits are all 0. Float64 representation implies that there is an implicit 1 before those 52 bits. So mantissa is a 1 followed by 52 zeros.  Which means 1+0/2+0/2²+0/2³+...+0/2⁵² = 1.

So 1 times 2 exponent 1 = 1×2 = 2. -2 since exponent is negative.

Likewise, the 8 next bytes, representing the 2nd float are [0, 0, 125, 53, 157, 56, 148, 22] (reversed, because little-endian again).

In binary

```
00000000 00000000 01111101 00110101 10011101 00111000 10010100 00010110
```

So, sign is 0
exponent is 00000000000 = 0. Which is a special case (a subnormal number), so exponent is -1022.
And mantissa is `0 0000 01111101 00110101 10011101 00111000 10010100 00010110` (including the implicit 0 for subnormal numbers).

so

```
(0/2**0 + 0/2**1 + 0/2**2 + 0/2**3 + 0/2**4 + 0/2**5 + 1/2**6 + 1/2**7 + 1/2**8 + 1/2**9 + 1/2**10 + 0/2**11 + 1/2**12 + 0/2**13 + 0/2**14 + 1/2**15 + 1/2**16 + 0/2**17 + 1/2**18 + 0/2**19 + 1/2**20 + 1/2**21 + 0/2**22 + 0/2**23 + 1/2**24 + 1/2**25 + 1/2**26 + 0/2**27 + 1/2**28 + 0/2**29 + 0/2**30 + 1/2**31 + 1/2**32 + 1/2**33 + 0/2**34 + 0/2**35 + 0/2**36 + 1/2**37 + 0/2**38 + 0/2**39 + 1/2**40 + 0/2**41 + 1/2**42 + 0/2**43 + 0/2**44 + 0/2**45 + 0/2**46 + 0/2**47 + 1/2**48 + 0/2**49 + 1/2**50 + 1/2**51 + 0/2**52)*2**-1022
```

Which, as expected is 6.80176343e-310

Now, if you had instead allocated a 2x2 array of int32, which is 2x2x4=16 bytes also, and happened to got the exact same bytes, then your array would have been

```
array([[         0, 3221225472],
       [2637730838,      32053]], dtype=uint32)
```

which is represented by bytes (in little endian):

```
0, 0, 0, 0
3221225472%256, (3221225472//2**8)%256, (3221225472//2**16)%256, (3221225472//2**24)
2637730838%256, (2637730838//2**8)%256, (2637730838//2**16)%256, (2637730838//2**24)
32053%256, (32053//2**8)%256, (32053//2**16)%256, (32053//2**24)
```

So `0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 22, 148, 56, 157, 53, 125, 0, 0`

The same bytes.

So, that the whole thing. Any bunch of bytes can be interpreted as `uint16`, or `int32` or `float64`. Bytes don't have types (other than "bytes").

You can "play" with this way more easily than I did, using `frombuffer` or `tobytes`

```py
test=np.array([[-2.00000000e+000, 6.80176343e-310]])
# Another array using the same memory, but another type and shape
t2=np.frombuffer(test, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(2,8)
t2
# array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 192],
#       [ 22, 148,  56, 157,  53, 125,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
# Let's change the first bit of the first float of `test` 
# That is the first bit of the last bytes of 1st row of t2 (because, little endian: first byte of 
# each number is the last)
t2[0,7]=64
# That is the sign bit of the first float of test. So , now test[0,0] should be +2 instead of -2
test
# array([[2.00000000e+000, 6.80176343e-310]])
# yep, it works

# or increase exponent by 1. That means that the last bit of exponent turn from 0 to 1. That is 12th bit of the 64 bits of the float
# So 4th bit (from the leftmost) of 2nd byte (so `t2[0,6]`) 
# Now it is 0. If 4th bit were 1, it would be 16.
# So 
t2[0,6]=16
# Normally test[0,0] should now be twice bigger, so 4
test
# array([[4.00000000e+000, 6.80176343e-310]])
# Yep, works again
```

Well, I got carried on. And that last game is quite remotely related to your question.
But it shows you: same bytes, 2 way to interpret them.

That is what happens with `np.empty`. It finds some bytes, without any attempt to select them from their content nor their type (again, there is no types. They are just bytes).

And then, it decide to interpret then as float64 (as you do with `test`) or as `uint8` (as I do with `t2`) or as whatever is required.